# Can get the cube to pop up (DirectX 11). Cube is not showing, only screen is being cleared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 3d, directx, game-development

I am trying to make a simple d3d11 program to rotate a cube.
But ultimately the cube doesnt seem to appear.
Only the screen is being cleared to blue but the cube doesnot show up.
I have been using this as my source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dgetstarted/getting-started-with-a-directx-game

The structure of my project is a
MainClass.cpp, MainClass.h (Handles window initializtion)
DeviceResources.cpp, DeviceResources.h (The Device Resources include device, context, etc.)
Renderer.cpp, Renderer.h (The renderer loads geometry and shaders. Most probably this is where i am going wrong)

Here is my Renderer.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include "DeviceResources.h"
class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer(std::shared_ptr<DeviceResources> deviceResources);
    ~Renderer();
    void CreateDeviceDependentResources();
    void CreateWindowSizeDependentResources();
    void Update();
    void Render();
private:
    HRESULT CreateShaders();
    HRESULT CreateCube();
    void CreateViewAndPerspective();

    bool m_done = false;

    std::shared_ptr<DeviceResources> m_deviceResources;

    typedef struct _constantBufferStruct {
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 world;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 view;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 projection;
    } ConstantBufferStruct;
    static_assert((sizeof(ConstantBufferStruct) % 16) == 0, "Constant Buffer size must be 16-byte aligned");

    typedef struct _vertexPositionColor {
        DirectX::XMFLOAT3 pos;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT3 color;
    } VertexPositionColor;

    typedef struct _vertexPositionColorTangent {
        DirectX::XMFLOAT3 pos;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT3 color;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT3 tangent;
    } VertexPositionColorTangent;

    ConstantBufferStruct m_constantBufferData;
    unsigned int m_indexCount;
    unsigned int m_frameCount;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_pVertexBuffer;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_pIndexBuffer;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> m_pVertexShader;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> m_pPixelShader;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> m_pInputLayout;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> m_pInputLayoutExtended;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_pConstantBuffer;
};
```

And here is my Renderer.cpp code :

```
#include "Renderer.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <stdexcept>

Renderer::Renderer(std::shared_ptr<DeviceResources> deviceResources) :
    m_deviceResources(deviceResources),
    m_frameCount(0)
{
    m_frameCount = 0;
}

Renderer::~Renderer() {}

void Renderer::CreateDeviceDependentResources() {
    auto CreateShaderTask = Concurrency::create_task([this]() {CreateShaders(); 
    m_done = true;
    });
    auto CreateCubeTask = CreateShaderTask.then([this]() {CreateCube(); });
}

void Renderer::CreateWindowSizeDependentResources() {
    CreateViewAndPerspective();
}

HRESULT Renderer::CreateShaders() {

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    ID3D11Device* device = m_deviceResources->GetDevice();
    FILE* vShader, * pShader;
    BYTE* bytes;

    size_t destSize = 4096;
    size_t bytesRead = 0;

    bytes = new BYTE[destSize];

    fopen_s(&vShader, "cubeVertexShader.cso", "rb");
    bytesRead = fread_s(bytes, destSize, 1, 4096, vShader);
    hr = device->CreateVertexShader(
        bytes,
        bytesRead,
        nullptr,
        &m_pVertexShader
    );

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC iaDesc[] =
    {
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
    0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
    0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    hr = device->CreateInputLayout(iaDesc,ARRAYSIZE(iaDesc), bytes, bytesRead, &m_pInputLayout);
    delete bytes;

    bytes = new BYTE[destSize];
    bytesRead = 0;
    fopen_s(&pShader, "cubePixelShader.cso", "rb");
    bytesRead = fread_s(bytes, destSize, 1, 4096, pShader);
    hr = device->CreatePixelShader(bytes, bytesRead, nullptr, &m_pPixelShader);

    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc(sizeof(ConstantBufferStruct), D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER );
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, nullptr, &m_pConstantBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw std::exception("Failed to Create Constant Buffer");
    fclose(vShader);
    fclose(pShader);
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Renderer::CreateCube() {
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ID3D11Device* device = m_deviceResources->GetDevice();
    VertexPositionColor CubeVertices[] =
    {
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0, 0, 0),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0, 0, 1),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0, 1, 0),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0, 1, 1),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1, 0, 0),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1, 0, 1),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 0),},
    {DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1),},
    };

    unsigned short CubeIndices[] =
    {
    0,2,1, // -x
    1,2,3,
    4,5,6, // +x
    5,7,6,
    0,1,5, // -y
    0,5,4,
    2,6,7, // +y
    2,7,3,
    0,4,6, // -z
    0,6,2,
    1,3,7, // +z
    1,7,5,
    };
    m_indexCount = ARRAYSIZE(CubeIndices);

    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbDesc(sizeof(CubeVertices), D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER);
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vData;
    ZeroMemory(&vData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    vData.pSysMem = CubeVertices;
    vData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&vbDesc, &vData, &m_pVertexBuffer);

    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibDesc(sizeof(CubeIndices), D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER);
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iData;
    ZeroMemory(&iData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    iData.pSysMem = CubeIndices;
    iData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    iData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&ibDesc, &iData, &m_pIndexBuffer);


    return hr;
}

void Renderer::CreateViewAndPerspective() {
    // Use DirectXMath to create view and perspective matrices.
    DirectX::XMVECTOR eye = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.7f, 1.5f, 0.f);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR at = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f, 0.f);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR up = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.f);
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(
        &m_constantBufferData.view,
        DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(
            DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtRH(
                eye,
                at,
                up
            )
        )
    );
    float aspectRatio = m_deviceResources->GetAspectRatio();
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(
        &m_constantBufferData.projection,
        DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(
            DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovRH(
                DirectX::XMConvertToRadians(70),
                aspectRatio,
                0.01f,
                100.0f
            )
        )
    );
}

void Renderer::Update() {
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(
        &m_constantBufferData.world,
        DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(
            DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(
                DirectX::XMConvertToRadians(
                    (float)m_frameCount++
                )
            )
        )
    );
    if (m_frameCount == MAXUINT) m_frameCount = 0;
}

void Renderer::Render() {
    while (!m_done) {

    }
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = m_deviceResources->GetDeviceContext();
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* renderTarget = m_deviceResources->GetRenderTarget();
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthStencil = m_deviceResources->GetDepthStencil();
    context->UpdateSubresource(m_pConstantBuffer.Get(), 0, nullptr, &m_constantBufferData, 0, 0);

    const float blue[4] = { 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f};
    context->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, blue);
    context->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencil, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTarget, depthStencil);
    UINT stride = sizeof(VertexPositionColor);
    UINT offset = 0;
    context->IASetVertexBuffers(
        0,
        1,
        m_pVertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(),
        &stride,
        &offset
    );
    context->IASetIndexBuffer(m_pIndexBuffer.Get(), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
    context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    context->IASetInputLayout(m_pInputLayout.Get());
    context->VSSetShader(m_pVertexShader.Get(), nullptr, 0);
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, m_pConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf());
    context->PSSetShader(m_pPixelShader.Get(), nullptr, 0);
    //context->DrawIndexed(m_indexCount, 0, 0);
    context->Draw(3, 0);
}
```

For more reference here are the shaders:-
Vertex Shader

```
cbuffer ModelViewProjectionBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix model;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

float4 main(float3 Position:POSITION, float3 Color:COLOR) : SV_POSITION// main is the default function name
{
    float4 pos = float4(Position, 1.0f);
    // Transform the position from object space to homogeneous projection space
    pos = mul(pos, model);
    pos = mul(pos, view);
    pos = mul(pos, projection);
    
    return pos;
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
float4 main(float4 position:SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.9f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6qNj.png)

Please help me analyze where i am going wrong.
Moreover, i am using visual studio 2019.

Edit: Some were asking a for a complete reproduction so here is the visual studio solution
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jt6fQgbRElpc9AYpbhYOyp-HCQL3WmEF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you checking all errors (HRESULT)? Difficult to say w/o a full reproducing code. Where's the window, swapchain, etc?

Comment: @SimonMourier i have posted a link to the complete visual studio solution . If u want u can check it out. It contains the entire source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing invalid memory accesses when reading the vertex and pixel buffers.

Also, on my computer, both shaders have a dozen of kbytes whilst the memory buffer you're reading them to has only 4096 bytes.

To fix your problem, increase the size of the memory buffer you're using to read the shader bytecode from disk and don't forget to update the elementcount in fread_s().

e.g.,

Renderer.cpp @ 35

```
    size_t destSize = 1024 * 1024; // CHANGE THE SIZE OF YOUR MEMORY BUFFER HERE
    size_t bytesRead = 0;

    bytes = new BYTE[destSize];

    fopen_s(&vShader, "cubeVertexShader.cso", "rb");
    bytesRead = fread_s(bytes, destSize * sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(BYTE), destSize, vShader);
    hr = device->CreateVertexShader(
        bytes,
        bytesRead,
        nullptr,
        &m_pVertexShader
    );
```

Do the same where you're reading the pixel shader.

PRO TIP: Pay attention to the debug output and you'll see important messages from d3d debug layer, like the one telling you that both shaders failed to be created :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I increased the buffer size for both vertex as well as pixel shader and it started working. Thank u very much :).